# Binary search tree add method not sorting every input - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, binary-search-tree

I am working on a Binary search tree and have a problem while adding the values to the tree.
When I add values(numbers) in order (descending or ascending) they are added in the right positions, but if I add value that is supposed to go somewhere in between values that are already in the tree, they don't get sorted. you can see that in the picture, the number [ 3 ] is added after 1, but it should be between [ 4 ] and [ 1 ]
So the question is, what exactly am I doing wrong and how to fix it

I am adding my code for the add function below the picture

[image]

The Node object

```
function Node(data){
this.data=data;
this.left=null;
this.right=null;}

function BinarySearchTree(){
this.root = null;
var current=null;
var newNode=null;

this.add = function(data){
    var root = this.root;
        if(!root){
            this.root= new Node(data);
            return;
        }else{
            if(this.ifExists(data)){
            }else{
                current=root;
                newNode= new Node(data);

                while(current){
                    if(data<current.data){
                        if(!current.left){
                                current.left=newNode;
                            break;
                        }else{
                                current= current.left;
                             }
                    }else{
                        if(!current.right){
                                current.right=newNode;
                            break;
                        }else{
                                current=current.right;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
this.ifExists=function(data){
         var current = this.root;
//       console.log(current);
         while(current){
             if(data==current.data){
                 return true;
             }
             current = data < current.value ? current.left : current.right;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

How I call the add function

```
var bst= new BinarySearchTree();
bst.add(7);
bst.add(8);
bst.add(4);
bst.add(1);
bst.add(15);
bst.add(67);
bst.add(9);
bst.add(3);
console.log(bst);
```

the output of console.log(bst);

[image]

Comment: you have some `else` `else` parts, which have no `if` before.

Comment: @NinaScholz  mistakenly copied the code into stackoverflow, just fixed the code. But this was not the problem

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You marked the 3 as in the wrong place, but the 1 should be a left child, as it is smaller than 4. The 3 is a right child as it should be.

Comment: You should add a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's clear where the problem is. If I add the missing code to  get this running, it works fine. I get a valid bst.

Comment: please add missing parts, like `ifExists` as well.

Comment: basically the value `3` is like in the picture in the right position, because it is smaller than `7` (left), smaller than `4` (left) and greater than `1` (right).

Comment: @Oram sory, i drew the numbers at the wrong side, I changed it, to the way that they are added

Comment: @NinaScholz I added the method ifExists

Comment: @Aina `3` should be next(right side) to number 1 i think in the binary search tree.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-binary-search-tree-javascript/

Comment: @MarkMeyer The problem is that I don't know where the problem is

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(bst);`?

Comment: @DerMolly just added the snapshot of the output

Comment: Your tree (but with 3 on the right of 1) is a **valid binary search tree**. So is the tree with 3 having 1 and 4 as children. The structure of tree depends on insertion order. A binary **search** tree has nothing to do with nodes being sorted.

Comment: @Aina your real output does not match the picture you drew of the tree. In fact the real output looks fine. Your code also looks fine. If anything, I wouldn't use the `isExists` function in the `add` function because it means you traverse the tree twice. Instead I would add a condition in the while loop `if (data==current.data) { return; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `3` should be on right side, because it is bigger than `1`. In your output this is true. In your picture you made an error there.

Other than that your tree is fine. The fact that 1 is smaller than 3 is correct, but a BST does only guaranty that an in-order tree walk yields an sorted list of the trees data and not that every smaller value is lower in the tree than a bigger value. If you perform an in order tree walk your BST would give you `1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 15`

If you do not know how to do a in order tree walk look at this:
[image: BST In-Order-Walk]
from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#/media/File:Sorted_binary_tree_inorder.svg)

Just note every data, when the point on the bottom of the node ist touched.